# If the validation fails focus should remain on same

Tags: javascript

In the below code i have 2 textbox .when i enter a value a validate if it is success it will move to next textbox and if it is failure it will alert and not move to another textbox.My aim if it is failure focus should remain on same textbox.

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {
        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

        var iReturn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length - 1; i++) {

            var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            if (!txtInput.match(re)) {
                iReturn = iReturn + 1;
            }
        }

        if (iReturn > 0) {
            alert("Failed...");//focus should remain on same textbox
        }
        else {
            alert("Success...");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('textInput').focus();` will do...

If you are passing reference of textInput in your case, then try `textInput.focus();`

You are passing only value to the ValidateRegExp function, Instead pass reference of the element. Change your event binding to the below,

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('" + txtField.ClientID + "'), '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

Change your js code to

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {
        var textValue = txtInput.value;
        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

        var iReturn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length - 1; i++) {

            var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            if (!textValue.match(re)) {
                iReturn = iReturn + 1;
            }
        }

        if (iReturn > 0) {
            //alert("Failed...");//focus should remain on same textbox
            textInput.focus();
        }
        else {
            alert("Success...");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Focus moves to another textbox when press tab

Comment: that is the behavior of focus, it will focus next element if you press tab. what is the issue in that?

Comment: If it is fail it should not move to another textbox

Comment: how you are binding the function ValidateRegExp(), `onblur` of the element?

Comment: using this   txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('" + txtField.ClientID + "').value, '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");

Answer (score 0):

use  `foucs()` method to do so

```
  if (iReturn > 0) {
            alert("Failed...");//focus should remain on same textbox
            txtInput.focus();
        }
```

Comment: then on your text box OnBlur event call the validation function

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `focus();` on the `textInput` reference.

### JavaScript :

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {
  var mySplitResult = [];
  mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

  var iReturn = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
    if (!txtInput.value.match(re)) {
      iReturn = iReturn + 1;
    }
  }

  if (iReturn > 0) {
    alert("Failed...");//focus should remain on same textbox
    txtInput.focus();
  }
  else {
    alert("Success...");
  }

}
```

In this case you will call `ValidateRegExp` with the argumets : NodeElement - usually obtained with `document.getElementById(...)` and the regexp `String`.

In your case :

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('" + txtField.ClientID + "'), '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

Demo Here http://jsbin.com/xomoq/1/edit